# Re-colour JTable after sorting

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a JTable, each row is coloured based on a value in the last column.

However, when i click the headers to sort the rows, the colours do not follow the rows.

I have tried calling my "colourTable" method on the JTable Mouse Exit event (Hacky i know) - with no luck.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

**This is my JTable**

[image: JTable]

**Where i tried calling the reColour method**

```
// If table headers are clicked for sorting, reset colours
    table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            Functions.colourTable(model, table);

        }
    });
```

**Colour Method**

```
static void colourTable(TableModel model, JTable table) {

    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new StatusColumnCellRenderer());

}
```

**Column cell renderer class**

```
public class StatusColumnCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

    Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

    // Get the mark value from the table (col 4)
    int mark = Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).toString());

    Color red = new Color(200, 44, 44);
    Color purple = new Color(163, 108, 223);
    Color green = new Color(36, 135, 44);

    // Fail
    if (mark < 40) {
        comp.setBackground(red.brighter());
        // Pass
    } else if (mark >= 40) {
        // Distinction
        if (mark >= 75) {
            comp.setBackground(purple.brighter());
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(green.brighter());
        }
    } else {
        comp.setBackground(null);
    }

    // Return the component
    return (comp);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int mark = Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
```

Don't get the value from the TableModel. The data in the TableModel is never sorted. Only the table view is displayed in a sorted order.

Instead just get the value from the table:

```
int mark = Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Dusty, but still true :)